# Diode to keep from shorting a battery, would it work?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I want to set up this circuit to allow instant uninterrupted power boosting of 6 volts. The chargers will only be connected at home when the circuit is disconnected from the motor. I only have 6amp 400V diodes so I have to put them in parallel.

The alternate circuit below would cause a voltage dip while switching and I want to try and avoid that.

The motor is 500 watts. The 6volt is half the Ah as the 36 volt so it is to be used sparingly thus I cannot regulate both as one.

The first schematic should work but am I missing some better way?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw3Iw1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[EDIT] Placed the diodes in the correct direction.

Comment: Diodes in parallel might not do what you expect.

Comment: I find the first diagram quite confusing ... when SW1 is open, you have 42V across the motor control, but only if you reverse the diodes that are still in circuit. When SW1 is closed, you *still* have 42V across the motor control (again, if you reverse those diodes). If you leave the diodes as they are, it seems like no current would flow?

Comment: You're right! I laid out the diodes in reverse. Heh.

Comment: Then, don't you still have 42V across the motor control? No current would even flow across the lower diodes ... the voltage on the right is more negative than the voltage at the closed SW1.

Comment: u planning to exceed 500W rating with this?

Comment: No, I plan to use the 6v boost to maintain 500 watt when the 36V are half depleted and need to climb a hill, I noticed the older the 36V batteries get the less voltage they maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler way:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8L7Va.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When SW1 is open D1 is forward biased, so the motor gets 36V (less forward voltage drop across D1). When Sw1 is closed it adds the 6V battery to make a total of 42V, and D1 is reverse biased so it disconnects the path between the batteries.

For lowest voltage drop when SW1 is open you should use a high current Schottky diode. When SW1 is closed there is no diode loss, so you get maximum boost!

Comment: But when SW1 open there is loss in the diode of a few %

Comment: @Tony Stewart  that's the price you pay for simplicity. But 0.6V/36V = 1.7%, a barely noticeable drop (eg. the difference between 21.4 mph and 21.0mph).

Comment: It is not the no load speed change of importance but rather the torque with peak demand at start with 150A surge. I doubt his diodes are rated at 0.6V at I surge as I recommended. but ok if he did

Comment: @Tony Stewart his diodes no. MBR4060 is rated for 400A peak and 0.6V drop at 20A (~700W output at 36V). A MOSFET would have lower loss _but_ could be tricky to drive correctly.

Comment: MBR4060 rises 165 mV from 10A rise @20A or 16.5mΩ, But motor at 500W/36V^2= 2.6Ω equiv full load and will have DCR~1/8th typ of this or 324 mΩ so starting torque is reduced by 5%.. no big deal

Comment: I had the diodes in the wrong direction and the switch on the wrong rail. I am rusty.

Comment: I have yet to order a Schottky diode so instead I use 3 6amp diodes in parallel thermally joined with thermal paste and it worked. Adding the diode to the circuit did reduce the oomph slightly during 36V take off but got me up steep long hills with little effort when switched to 42V. Mission accomplished. –

Answer (score 0):

SW1 diodes will short out 6V battery .

> 36V if rated for 500W means ~14A rated load current and 8~10x surge currents or 112~200A peak currents so diodes should be rated for Vf@200A for low drop.

There are many issues.

- extending Ah capacity from weakest link Bat1 or Bat2
- stress on weakest battery voltage drop and resulting warped plates from EMF forces, conduction losses
- power commutation logic
- power commutation losses and continuous arc prevention.
- battery balance series cells

*I will focus on the last item, others can focus on the diode logic switch.*

To make this perfect requires ESR of both batteries to be about

ESR of 6V =1/6 of ESR of 36V

This may require proper sizing of both batteries to be about same Ah rating to achieve this .

ie incremental drop in voltage / rise in current = ESR (when charger is off) to balance losses and improve load regulation.

DCR of the motor must be >10% of battery string ESR for a max surge current drop in battery voltage of <=10%

---

## Observations & Conclusions

your 6V Ah rating of 50% of 36V bat when it should be same. Condition or health of batteries affects Ah and ESR directly so do a resistor or headlamp load test to verify ESR such that 6V ESR=<1/6 of 36V battery ESR.

then, it will work as if it is a balanced 42 V battery , assuming none of the internal cells are mismatched and defective. Check specific gravity of all cells for perfect matching.

Then for switching use a 25A relay or switch with Bruce's fine arrangment which will lose about 1 V depending on power rating of diode.

[**Here**](http://%20http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/1376383?k=&pkeyword=&pv915=2624&pv915=1704&pv915=1703&pv915=765&pv915=404&pv915=2645&pv915=590&pv915=2646&pv915=2407&pv915=484&pv915=2096&pv915=1246&pv915=2647&pv915=2648&pv915=734&pv915=655&pv915=741&pv915=411&pv915=677&pv915=704&FV=fff40015%2Cfff8007f&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=250) are some good choices for Sch Diodes with <0.5V drop at surge current

or try a SPDT relay rated>25A with snubber RC across contacts to suppress arcing during load switch for a 0.5V boost over the Schottky Diode approach.

I might consider **[this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160528214611/http://www.digikey.com:80/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G8JR-1A7T-R-DC12/Z2716-ND/1618708)** 50A Relay rated for 150A surge

*BTW,FWIW, CCA and CA and Ah smart battery testers measure ESR from V/I drop compared to a known pulse R load to determine SoC of the battery.*

## Another approach is use your 2nd schematic and replace SPDT switch with dual Nch MOSFETS Cost $1 (pc)  Dual N-channel 60 V, 14 mΩ standard level MOSFET

[image]

but replace the 1mF with RF caps and add 60V TVS protection.